# How to include Example with playable in Godoc

Tags: go

How do you make Golang example playable?

I have a below code:

```
func Example_authenticate() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    // Output: JSON
}
```

Do I need to add playable code somewhere to get this in Doc?

Comment: In local godoc you mean or godoc.org?

Comment: No for generating `godoc` for my package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run `godoc` with the `-play` flag:

```
$ godoc --help
..........
  -play=false: enable playground in web interface
```

For example run `godoc -http=:9020 -play` then go to `http://localhost:9020/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal`

To install `godoc` locally:

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc
```

Comment: That is for main Godoc.org but I want my own package godoc with play. Is this possible?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper it depends on running a local version of the playground, so you have to run your own local godoc server with playground enabled.